# Editing a code to create a filter based on a condition and then stripping the condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

SO,

I'm looking for some help making a bit of code so that it also includes an if statement so that the filter is only added if the line contains `(BIPL)` but then stripping it out of the filters list once it's added...

```
1test,tester,testing (BIPL),no,yes
2test,tester,testing,no,yes
3data,datas,datatest (BIPL),yes,no
```

Current code...

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as old_csv:
    filters = {(row[0].lower(), row[1][:3].upper(), row[2].upper()) for row in csv.reader(old_csv, delimiter=',')}
```

Effectively the outcome would be as follows, just in a different format.

```
1test,TES,TESTING
3data,DAT,DATATEST
```

It should be a simple change but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`csv.reader` can accept an iterator as its first argument (not just file handles). So you can define a generator which yields only those lines which contain `'(BIPL)'` and send that to `csv.reader`:

```
import csv
import re

def only_bipl(f):
    for line in f:
        if '(BIPL)' in line:
            yield re.sub(r'\s*\(BIPL\)', '', line)

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as old_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(only_bipl(old_csv), delimiter=',')
    filters = {(row[0].lower(), row[1][:3].upper(), row[2].upper()) for row in reader}
```

---

Note the above will yield *any* line that contains `'(BIPL)'` anywhere. A better, more targeted alternative would be to match only those lines which contain `'(BIPL)'` at the end of the third item. You can do that using an `if-clause` inside the set comprehension:

```
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as old_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(old_csv, delimiter=',')
    filters = {(row[0].lower(), row[1][:3].upper(), row[2][:-6].strip().upper())
               for row in reader
               if row[2].endswith('(BIPL)')}
```

Comment: yield re.sub(' ?\\(BIPL\\)', '', line)

Comment: You never accepted the suggested edit on `reader` misspelt `reder` :P but yeah either way works good enough. It's working flawlessly for my needs.